# Loosing HDMI audio device after some time of inactivty

Tags: nvidia, sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, hdmi

I got myself a **GeForce RTX 2060** for the living room HTPC.

lspci shows:

> [ VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX
> 2060] (rev a1)]

I am currently trying to get image+audio through the HDMI of the card to my TV, which works with but one problem: After some time the audio device gets disconnected (though the TV is still running and showing the GUI) and the audio is routed to the USB receiver of my headset. In this case I have to set the device again to TU 104 HD Audio (the nvidia card HDMI link) in audio manager.

Now the problem is that I am not able to find evidence when or why the disconnect happens. I've gone through kernel, dmesg, xorgr and syslog when it happens, but I am not able to find a trace of the device disconnect.

Is there any log file or another log level I can access to find the reason for the disconnect?

This problem does not occur when I configured the audio to the **LineOut** of the onboard soundcard.

---

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, kernel 5.8.1,
Asus ROG Strix B350 Bios 5406 with AMD Ryzen 2700,
nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 running binary driver 450.66

Comment: The second post where I didn't find the card on the nvidia site. What card is it? GTX 2600? Did not find a Geforce 2600. Best is to post the outpout of `lspci` - copy and paste it from the terminal into your qeustion by editing it

Comment: It's a 2060, as I've written, not a 2600 :)  [ VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX 2060] (rev a1)]

Comment: I've edited your answer- so that someone might help you with the correct information